# Why don't I crawl the data by scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am a newbie in scrapy and just tried to crawl the hackernews. I am able to get the all the links and title from the site but the empty title and link are also getting crawled all along the data. How to avoid this or maybe i have done some error in declaring xpaths.

**I dont know why is it faulty???**

```html
import re
import os
# import dateime 
# from datetime import date 
import scrapy 
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class ConcungItem(scrapy.Spider):
    name="detailcc"
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://concung.com/sua-bot-101586.html",
            callback=self.parse
        )
    def parse(self, response):
        for a in response.xpath('.//div[@class="hot-deal row product-list-cat"]'):
            for j in a.xpath('.//div[@class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3   ]'):
                for m in j.xpath('.//div[@class="product-item"]'):
                    url_=m.xpath('.//h4[@class="item-title font-weight-normal pt-2"]/a/@href').extract_first()
                    name=m.xpath('.//h4[@class="item-title font-weight-normal pt-2"]/a/text()').extract_first()
                    price=m.xpath('.//div[@class="block-prices"]/strong[@class="product-price"]/text()').extract_first()
                    yield{
                        'url_':url_,
                        'name':name,
                        'price':price
                        }
```

**when it run, i dont see data on web??? Help me, pls ???**

```html
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Darwin-19.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': '2020-10-03_concung_items.csv', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1'}
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 749813a6d76c4b45
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/Users/macbookpro/Thuyltd.hcm/Scrapy/Scrapy/concung/concung/spiders/concung-items.py", line 10, in start_requests
    yield scrapy.Requests(
AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'Requests'
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.007126,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 3, 13, 7, 45, 874231),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 50089984,
 'memusage/startup': 50089984,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 3, 13, 7, 45, 867105)}
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: concung)
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Darwin-19.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'concung', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'concung.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['concung.spiders']}
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 31614e4b3e4bc1f7
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-10-03 20:07:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/scrapy", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 146, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 100, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 154, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 58, in run
    self.crawler_process.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 309, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1282, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1262, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 765, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could get you more feedback, or even help you figure out the issue for yourself.